# Dataset type mismatch

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

My Sample Java Snippet

```java
public class SampleInsert {
  public static void runCode(Dataset cemData){
}
```

Which I need to call from my scala Object using the below snippet

```scala
val sampleDS = spark.sql("""select * from someTable""").as[ExceptionRecord]
val sampleInsert = new SampleInsert
sampleInsert.runCode(sampleDS)
```

And I am getting the below error while doing that

```
found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[ExceptionRecord]
required: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
```

ExceptionRecord - is a case class I have created in scala to define the dataset.

I cannot make any changes in the Java class so I have to somehow make changes in my Scala object to avoid issue type mismatch issue.

Instead of

```scala
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[ExceptionRecord]
```

The type has to be

```scala
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
```

Comment: Don't think you can do better than a `.asInstanceOf[Dataset[_]]` here, did you try it?

Comment: Is it possible for you to modify your Java code to not use a raw type?

Comment: @user - Possible but will I be able to use the same Dataset in Java class? In that case I think both places will have the same type and once the control comes to Java class I can handle it further.